# Roots of a given equation

Tags: roots

How can I show that the equation 
$$e^x-\ln(x)-2^{2014}=0$$
has exactly two positive roots?

Comment: $\ln(\alpha) < 0 \quad \forall \alpha\in(0,1)$... So your thoughts are wrong

Comment: It was a good edit!!

Answer (score 3):

Define $f(x) = e^x - \ln x$. Then

$$f'(x) = e^x - \frac 1 x \implies f''(x) = e^x + \frac 1 {x^2} \ge 1$$

for all $x > 0$. That is, $f$ is concave up, so it's shaped like the letter $U$. Hence there are at most two positive roots. Now use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

It goes to infinity at both $0$ and $\infty,$ and the derivative is $\exp x - 1/x,$ which has exactly one zero, and the function is negative at that zero.